# EF Core DbUpdateConcurrencyException on insert

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, azure-sql-database

I am using the following tools: Azure SQL Server, .NET Core 3.1, EF Core 5.0

I have a main table called `Channels` and another table called `ChannelWikiTopics`. Whenever there is an update to a *channel* in `Channels`, I delete all the `ChannelWikiTopics` belonging to that channel and then I insert new ones instead.

I do this to save me the trouble of checking which wikiTopic values I have and then updating them. So I just delete them all and then insert them again. I know this may be controversial thing to do, but I'm not looking to change that.

The issue is that whenever I have a **new** `Channel`, aka I don't have any *wikiTopics* belonging to that *channel* (fist time insert, but the table not necessarily is empty, just first time for this particular channel) the insert happens without problems. But when I try to do an update for the *channel* meaning it already exists, the inserts fail. But only in the `ChannelWikiTopics` table, the rest works fine.

My entities are as follows:

```
public class ChannelWikiTopic
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; } ///<value>DB generated id to identify this WikiTopicCat topic.</value>
    public string TopicCategory { get; set; } ///<value>Topic id as identified by WikiTopicCat standards.</value>
    [ForeignKey("Channel")]
    public string YTChannelId { get; set; } ///<value>Channel id given by YT to the channel and also used by Channels as a primary id.</value>
    public virtual Channel Channel { get; set; } ///<value>Reference property to the channel to which this Wiki topic category belong.</value>
}

public class Channel
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string YTChannelId { get; set; } ///<value>Id YouTube gives to the channel and it is used here as a primary key.</value>
    ... other irrelevant properties ...
    public ICollection<ChannelWikiTopic> ChannelWikiTopics { get; set; } ///<value>A collection of all the WikiTopicCategories assigned to this channel</value>
}
```

The operations I perform in my repository are:

```
public IDictionary<string,Channel> RecallChannels(string[] channelIds)
{
        try
        {
            //retrieve all the pertinent entities from DB
            _ChannelIdDictionary = _context.Channel.Where(c => channelIds.Contains(c.YTChannelId)).ToDictionary(c => c.YTChannelId, c => c);
            var wikiDic = _context.ChannelWikiTopics.Where(wt => channelIds.Contains(wt.YTChannelId)).ToList();

            //remove all the wikitopics to avoid duplicates in db, since I'm inserting them later on again
            if (wikiDic.Count > 0)
                _context.ChannelWikiTopics.RemoveRange(wikiDic);

            //_context.SaveChanges();

            return _ChannelIdDictionary;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, ex.Message);
            throw ex;
        }
}
```

If I were to uncomment `_context.SaveChanges();` here, then it would work perfectly. But I don't think it should matter. Because the EF is deleting the *wikiTopics* before deleting anyway before inserting.

Then I update the entity

```
public void UpdateChannel(Channel channelEntity)
{
        try
        {
            if (_context.Entry(channelEntity).State != EntityState.Added)
                _context.Channel.Update(channelEntity);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, ex.Message);
            throw ex;
        }
}
```

And then I save the changes

```
public async Task Commit()
{
        try
        {
            _ = await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, ex.Message);
            throw ex;
        }
}
```

Here is the SQL generated by EF Core according to the logs

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

UPDATE [Channel] SET ...lots of fields...
WHERE [YTChannelId] = @p16;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

UPDATE [Channel] 
SET ...lots of columns...
WHERE [YTChannelId] = @p33;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

UPDATE [Channel] 
SET ...lots of columns...
WHERE [YTChannelId] = @p50;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

DELETE FROM [ChannelWikiTopics]
WHERE [Id] = @p144;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

DELETE FROM [ChannelWikiTopics]
WHERE [Id] = @p145;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

DELETE FROM [ChannelWikiTopics]
WHERE [Id] = @p146;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

DELETE FROM [ChannelWikiTopics]
WHERE [Id] = @p147;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

DELETE FROM [ChannelWikiTopics]
WHERE [Id] = @p148;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

DELETE FROM [ChannelWikiTopics]
WHERE [Id] = @p149;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

DELETE FROM [ChannelWikiTopics]
WHERE [Id] = @p150;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

INSERT INTO [ChannelWikiTopics] ([Id], [TopicCategory], [YTChannelId])
VALUES (@p151, @p152, @p153),
(@p154, @p155, @p156),
(@p157, @p158, @p159),
(@p160, @p161, @p162),
(@p163, @p164, @p165),
(@p166, @p167, @p168),
(@p169, @p170, @p171);
```

Everything looks in order. Nothing suspicious. I even checked that the Ids that were being deleted were not being reused and they are not.

Ids being deleted for this run were:

```
@p144='0c25919e-d420-4693-e170-08d8599b09fa', @p145='33aecae6-ab86-4539-e172-08d8599b09fa', 
@p146='6407d3f0-8a64-4e80-e171-08d8599b09fa', @p147='a080d930-cf94-462c-e16f-08d8599b09fa', 
@p148='abe51051-0db6-4bbf-e16d-08d8599b09fa', @p149='cb2ac5ed-cce0-426b-e16e-08d8599b09fa', 
@p150='d1bca992-4a6f-443c-e173-08d8599b09fa'
```

Ids being inserted for this run were:

```
@p151='9340713c-c754-4215-5fda-08d8599b9bfb', @p154='8a2b8bda-15a4-4f28-5fd6-08d8599b9bfb', 
@p157='b354a6bb-8927-4cec-5fd7-08d8599b9bfb', @p160='92731e08-4d28-4076-5fd8-08d8599b9bfb',
@p163='6caa4995-79d7-4e3c-5fd9-08d8599b9bfb', @p166='e8a41a0a-476a-45d1-5fdb-08d8599b9bfb',
@p169='261d3b48-c2cf-4712-5fdc-08d8599b9bfb'
```

I even tried performing the insert myself directly in SQL Server Management Studio by replacing the parameters in the log with their respective value and it worked. It performed the insert without deleting the older ones. Which of course makes sense since there is no constraint that says the pair `<[TopicCategory], [YTChannelId]>` should be unique.

Also it is worth noting that there is no trigger affecting either one of the tables. I saw that that is a common issue with this kind of error. And of course there is no actual concurrency problem since I am the only user currently and there is no background process doing anything either.

In case it is useful here is the create table script

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ChannelWikiTopics]
(
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [TopicCategory] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [YTChannelId] [nvarchar](450) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_ChannelWikiTopics] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
                    WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ChannelWikiTopics] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_ChannelWikiTopics_Channel_YTChannelId] 
        FOREIGN KEY([YTChannelId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Channel] ([YTChannelId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ChannelWikiTopics] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ChannelWikiTopics_Channel_YTChannelId]
GO
```

Please let me know if anything is missing or if something wasn't clear enough

Thanks!

Comment: Just in case, 2 questions: 1. What about the message contained in the DBUpdateConcurrencyException? Is there anything specific? 2. Did you find a minimum reproducible example? I mean, are all the 'unimportamt' columns really removed from the actual tables and the issue still occurs?

Comment: @AlexeyAdadurov 1) nothing specific, just the generic *expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s)* 2) there is not much to remove actually, given that ```channelWikiTopics``` only has 3 columns. But if I were to comment out the part where I insert the *wikitopics*, but keep everything else (deleting the wikitopics and updating channels) it works. And this happens every time no matter how many channels I choose to update. I've tried anything between 1 to 2.5M channels. It all works fine in the 1st insert in ChannelWikiTopics, but not thereafter.

Comment: @AlexeyAdadurov please notice that if I delete the *wikitopics* belonging to the channels being updated and immediately commit that deletion it works. It only doesn't work as part of the bigger transaction detailed in the sql shown in the post (which happen in that order btw)

Comment: @gris This problem is not difficult. The trouble is that it needs to be troubleshooting and breakpoint debugging is required. At each step, the part that interacts with the database, please check carefully, take out the statement to execute, see if it is the expected effect, and finally report the error part for analysis.

Comment: @gris If possible, it is recommended to upload the sample code after hiding the confidential information, and the project can reproduce the problem.